# Optimizing the storage and processing of large series of data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I have a case here that I would like to have some opinions from the experts :)

**Situation:**

- I have a data structure with ´Int32´ and ´Double´ values, with a total of 108 bytes.
- I have to process a large series of this data structure. Its something like (conceptual, I will use a for loop instead):

```cs
double result = 0;
foreach(Item item in series)
{        
    double += //some calculation based on item
}
```

- I expect the size of the series to be about 10 Mb.
- To be useful, the whole series must be processed. It's all or nothing.
- The series data will **never** change.

**My requirements:**

- Memory consumption is **not** an issue. I think that nowadays, if the user doesn't have a few dozen Mb free on his machine, he probably has a deeper problem.
- Speed **is** a concern. I want the iteration to be as fast as possible.
- **No** unmanaged code, or interop, or even unsafe.

**What I would like to know**

- Implement the item data structure as a value or reference type? From what I know, value types are cheaper, but I imagine that on each iteration a copy will be made for each item if I use a value type. Is this copy faster than a heap access?
- Any real problem if I implement the accessors as anonymous properties? I believe this will increase the footprint. But also that the getter will be inlined anyway. Can I safely assume this?
- I'm seriously considering to create a very large static readonly array of the series directly in code (it's rather easy do this with the data source). This would give me a 10Mb assembly. Any reason why I should avoid this?

Hope someone can give me a good opinion on this.

Thanks

Comment: Code it both ways and profile it. Then you'll know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Implement the item data structure as a value or reference type? From what I know, value types are cheaper, but I imagine that on each iteration a copy will be made for each item if I use a value type. Is this copy faster than a heap access?

Code it both ways and profile it aggressively on real-world input. Then you'll know exactly which one is faster.

> Any real problem if I implement the accessors as anonymous properties?

Real problem? No.

> I believe this will increase the footprint. But also that the getter will be inlined anyway. Can I safely assume this?

You can only safely assume things guaranteed by the spec. It's not guaranteed by the spec.

> I'm seriously considering to create a very large static readonly array of the series directly in code (it's rather easy do this with the data source). This would give me a 10Mb assembly. Any reason why I should avoid this?

I think you're probably worrying about this too much.

I'm sorry if my answer seems dismissive. You're asking random people on the Internet to speculate which of two things is faster. We can guess, and we might be right, but you could just code it both ways in the blink of an eye and know exactly which is faster. So, just do it?

However, I always code for correctness, readability and maintainability at first. I establish reasonable performance requirements up front, and I see if my implementation meets them. If it does, I move on. If I need more performance from my application, I profile it to find the bottlenecks and then I start worrying.

You're asking about a trivial computation that takes ~10,000,000 / 108 ~= 100,000 iterations. Is this even a bottleneck in your application? Seriously, you are overthinking this. Just code it and move on.

Answer (score 1):

That's 100,000 loops which in CPU time is sod all. Stop over thinking it and just write the code. You're making a mountain out of a molehill.

Answer (score 0):

Speed is subjective. How do you load your data and how much data is inside your process elsewhere? Loading the data will be the slowest part of your app if you do not need complex parsing logic to create your struct.

I do think you ask this question because you have a struct of 108 bytes of size which you do perform calculations on and you wonder why your app is slow. Please note that structs are passed by value which means if you pass the struct to one or more method during your calcuations or you fetch it from a List you will create a copy of the struct every time. This is indeed very costly.

Change your struct to a class and expose only getters to be sure to have a read only object only. That should fix your perf issues.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to separate data from code, so regarding your "big array embedded in the code question", I say don't do that.
Use LINQ for calculations on entire series; the speed is good.
Use a Node class for each point if you want more functionality.

I used to work with such large series of data. They were points that you plot on a graph. Originally they were taken every ms or less. The datasets were huge. Users wanted to apply different formulas to these series and have that displayed. It looks to me that your problem might be similar.

To improve speed we stored different zoom levels of the points in a db. Say every ms, then aggregate for every minute, every hr, every day, etc (whatever users needed). When users zoomed in or out we would load the new values from db instead of performing the calculations right then. We would also cache the values so users don't have to go to the db all the time.
Also if the users wanted to apply some formulas to the series (like in your case), the data is less in size.